# XSLT - get the string before last '/'

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the string for example :

```
 <path> c:/users/xyz/test_files/test.xml </path>
```

and I would like to get the string before last '/' that is:

c:/users/xyz/test_files

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(.,'/')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$tokens[not(.=$tokens[last()])]" separator="/"/>
```

This assumes the current context is `path`.

Comment: This works. If you want a one-liner, or to directly store the result in a variable, you can use this as well: <xsl:param name="base path" select="string-join($tokens[not(.=$tokens[last()])],'/')"/>

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="path">
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="string-join(tokenize(., '/')[position() lt last()], '/')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

should do.